# the way to connect two div with a line in svg

Tags: angularjs, svg, drag

I'm trying to make a workflow designer. Users can drag and build their own 
workflow. But connecting a line between two div can be a problem for me. I try 
to calculate the svg's position and size to draw the line.but when two div 
getting too close.the line will appear in the wrong place. I try to judge 
different position between two div (top-left,top-right,bottom-left,bottom-
right).

```
drawLine = function() {
    var lineX, lineY, moveX, moveY, svgPath;
    svgPath = $element[0].querySelector('.svgPath');
    if (Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) > $scope.svgLineClientWidth + 20) {
      $element[0].style.width = Math.abs($scope.to.x - $scope.from.x) - $scope.svgLineClientWidth + 'px';
      $element[0].style.height = Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y) + $scope.svgLineClientHeight + 'px';
      if ($scope.to.y > $scope.from.y) {
        $element[0].style.top = $scope.from.y + 'px';
        if ($scope.to.x >= $scope.from.x) {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.from.x + $scope.svgLineClientWidth + 'px';
          moveX = 0 + "";
          moveY = $scope.svgLineClientHeight / 2 + "";
          lineX = (Math.abs($scope.to.x - $scope.from.x) - $scope.svgLineClientWidth - 16) + "";
          lineY = (Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y) - 15) + "";
          return svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        } else {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.from.x - ($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x - $scope.svgLineClientWidth) + 'px';
          moveX = (Math.abs($scope.to.x - $scope.from.x) - $scope.svgLineClientWidth) + "";
          moveY = $scope.svgLineClientHeight / 2 + "";
          lineX = -(Math.abs($scope.to.x - $scope.from.x) - $scope.svgLineClientWidth - 16) + "";
          lineY = (Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y) - 15) + "";
          return svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        }
      } else {
        $element[0].style.top = $scope.from.y - (Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y)) + 'px';
        if ($scope.to.x > $scope.from.x) {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.from.x + $scope.svgLineClientWidth + 'px';
          moveX = 0 + "";
          moveY = (Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y) + $scope.svgLineClientHeight / 2) + "";
          lineX = (Math.abs($scope.to.x - $scope.from.x) - $scope.svgLineClientWidth - 12) + "";
          lineY = -(Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y) - 15) + "";
          return svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        } else {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.from.x - ($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x - $scope.svgLineClientWidth) + 'px';
          moveX = (Math.abs($scope.to.x - $scope.from.x) - $scope.svgLineClientWidth) + "";
          moveY = (Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y) + $scope.svgLineClientHeight / 2) + "";
          lineX = -(Math.abs($scope.to.x - $scope.from.x) - $scope.svgLineClientWidth - 12) + "";
          lineY = -(Math.abs($scope.to.y - $scope.from.y) - 15) + "";
          return svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        }
      }
    } else {
      $element[0].style.width = Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) + $scope.svgLineClientWidth + 'px';
      $element[0].style.height = Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) - $scope.svgLineClientHeight + 'px';
      if ($scope.to.y > $scope.from.y) {
        $element[0].style.top = $scope.from.y + $scope.svgLineClientHeight + 'px';
        if ($scope.to.x > $scope.from.x) {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.from.x + 'px';
          moveX = $scope.svgLineClientHeight + "";
          moveY = 0 + "";
          lineX = Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) - 20 + "";
          lineY = Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) - $scope.svgLineClientHeight - 16 + "";
          svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        } else {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.to.x + 'px';
          moveX = Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) + $scope.svgLineClientWidth - $scope.svgLineClientHeight + "";
          moveY = 0 + "";
          lineX = '-' + Math.abs(Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) - 20) + "";
          lineY = Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) - $scope.svgLineClientHeight - 16 + "";
          svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        }
      } else {
        $element[0].style.top = $scope.from.y - Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) + $scope.svgLineClientHeight + 'px';
        if ($scope.to.x > $scope.from.x) {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.from.x + 'px';
          moveX = $scope.svgLineClientHeight + "";
          moveY = Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) - $scope.svgLineClientHeight + "";
          lineX = Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) - 20 + "";
          lineY = -(Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) - $scope.svgLineClientHeight - 16) + "";
          svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        } else {
          $element[0].style.left = $scope.to.x + 'px';
          moveX = Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) + $scope.svgLineClientHeight + "";
          moveY = Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) - $scope.svgLineClientHeight + "";
          lineX = -(Math.abs($scope.from.x - $scope.to.x) - 20) + "";
          lineY = -(Math.abs($scope.from.y - $scope.to.y) - $scope.svgLineClientHeight - 16) + "";
          svgPath.setAttribute('d', "M" + moveX + " " + moveY + "l" + lineX + " " + lineY);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

[image]

because the div's size is too small that the line can't appear like this:
[image]

So is there another better way to connect two div with a line? A more simple and exact way to calculate the line's moveTo and lineTo?

Here is the demo 
   https://plnkr.co/edit/ALVkJljbaek6dNTiWZGD?p=preview

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you mean by a "better way".  What is the "right place" for the line?

Comment: thanks for editing  :)

Comment: getBoundingClientRect will get the each div's position and size. That should make things simpler.